# How to copy image to a new variable

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying this code, but I'm doing something wrong.

```
class Photo(TimestampedModel):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
image_600 = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                  processors=[ResizeToFill(600, 600)],
                                  format='JPEG',
                                  options={'quality': 70})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.image = self.compressImage(self.image)
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def compressImage(self, image):
    imageTemporary = Image.open(image)
    format = imageTemporary.format
    outputIoStream = BytesIO()
    imageTemporary.save(outputIoStream, format=format, quality=70)
    outputIoStream.seek(0)
    image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField', image.name,
                                 format, None, None)
    return image

def resizeImage(self, image):
    basewidth = 600

    img = Image.open(image)
    format = img.format

    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))

    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    outputIoStream = BytesIO()
    img.save(outputIoStream, format=format, quality=70)
    outputIoStream.seek(0)  

    image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField', image.name,
                                 format, None, None)
    return image
```

The idea is to create a second image (`image_card`), with a new size.

In the end, I get an image for `image_card` but not for `image`.

The methods `compressImage()` and `resizeImage()` works correctly, but I suspect that resizeImage is getting the same image instance.

If I comment the `line self.image_card = self.resizeImage(self.image)` , `image` works again.

Comment: We need to see the resizeImage method in order to help you.

Comment: Be careful to create the resized image only when the object is created because in case you update the image it will not update the resized one.

Comment: Davide, thats exactly whats going on. But I didnt want to wait for the oject to be created. I wanted to create the resized version together.